# BMI calculator using Event Handlers computation

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

So While working on my BMI calculator, I cannot seem to get the computation section working. I have three text boxes which has information needed to complete the calculation, Height in Feet, Height in Inches, and Weight in lbs.

Here is my code. What seems to be my mistake?

```
<form id="US" runat="server" visible="true">
   <div style="background-color:#4DB8FF; width:350px; height:300px; margin:auto; text-align:center; font-family:Arial">
        <h4>
            Body Mass Index Calculator 
            <asp:Button id="btnUS" runat="server" text="US" OnClick="btnUS_Click" /> 
            <asp:Button id="btnMetric" runat="server" Text="Metric" OnClick="btnMetric_Click" /> <br />

            <script runat="server">
                void btnUS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    this.US.Visible = true;
                    this.Metric.Visible = false;
                }

                void btnMetric_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    this.US.Visible = false;
                    this.Metric.Visible = true;
                }

                void calcUS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    string operand1 = heightus.Text;
                    string operand2 = heightus1.Text;
                    string operand3 = weightus.Text;

                    string bmi = resultus.Text;

                    double number;

                    bool isOperand1Number = Double.TryParse(operand1, out number);
                    bool isOperand2Number = Double.TryParse(operand2, out number);
                    bool isOperand3Number = Double.TryParse(operand3, out number);


                    if (isOperand1Number && isOperand2Number && isOperand3Number)
                    {
                        bmi = (((operand3 / ((operand1 * 12) + operand2) * (operand1 * 12) + operand2))) * 703);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("Please type a numeric value into each of the text boxes.");
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </h4>

                  <asp:label ID="lbl1" Text="Height:" runat="server" />
                     <asp:TextBox ID="heightus" runat="server" />feet<br />
                     <asp:TextBox ID="heightus1" runat="server" />inch(es)<br />
                  <asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text="Weight:" runat="server" />
                     <asp:TextBox ID="weightus" runat="server" />lbs<br />
                <br />
                     <asp:Button ID="calcUS" Text="Calculate"  OnClick="calcUS_Click" runat="server" />
                     <asp:Button ID="clearUS" runat="server" Text="Clear"/> 
                <br /><br />
                  <asp:Label ID="lbl3" Text="Results:" runat="server" />
                     <asp:TextBox ID="resultus" runat="server" /> <br />


    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what problem are you facing? What is not working etc. That will be helpful in addressing your problem.

Comment: First, you are setting `bmi` but then you aren't setting that to anything on the page to see the result (like `resultus.Text = myResult`). Second, you are using strings for calculations. Third, you should move all that code to the code-behind. Fourth, just use JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're initializing your  isOperand1Number  isOperand2Number and  isOperand3Number booleans properly. Put a few debug statements and output your results along the way so you can see where this fails.

You may also want to type cast string bmi,operand1,2,3 into integers. They stay strings when you try to add them and compute them at:

```
        bmi = (((operand3 / ((operand1 * 12) + operand2) * (operand1 * 12) + operand2))) * 703);
```